# How to configure debug environment for vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, vscode-debugger

I am struggling to debug my project.

The directory structure is as follows:

Root Dir

- ModuleA

  - Submodule1
  - Submodule2
- ModuleB

  - Submodule3
  - Submodule4

When debugging a python script within Submodule3 (e.g. `python ModuleB/Submodule3/script.py --arg-one string`) which imports from ModuleA, I am getting module import errors. When running via CLI, running `export PYTHONPATH=$PWD` from the root dir resolves the import errors, but I cannot figure out how to configure the path to enable the debugger

Note: I am on macOS and I use pyenv via homebrew for my python installations. Additionally the project contains a venv at ./venv

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Configure `env` in `launch.json` and add `PYTHONPATH` variable.

**Example**:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "E:\\Desktop\\project"
            }
        }
    ],
    
}
```

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_env